# Oscilloscope training resources

Tags: oscilloscope, basic

I would like to learn to use an oscilloscope properly. I used them a few times at school, but that was a long time ago and I've forgotten most of what I learned about their use.

I'm now working with sensors and PLC based control systems driving hydro-electric turbines. I think being able to look at the waveforms of sensor signals and check for noise etc would be useful in troubleshooting applications. I've got a cheap USB oscilloscope (SainSmart DDS120) so: where are the best online training resources for learning how to use an oscilloscope?

Answer (score 1):

Oscilloscope manufacturers often have "generic" basic tutorials - before they then discuss model-specific features, which wouldn't apply to your specific 'scope (if the tutorials are from a different manufacturer, of course).  Learning about oscilloscope probes and their effects on signals, is also important IMHO.

This page has links for Tektronix learning resources about oscilloscopes and probes, for example, much of which are applicable across all manufacturers:

http://www.tek.com/learning/oscilloscope-tutorial

I would expect other big 'scope manufacturers to have similar resources.

---

FYI on the link above, Tektronix do (attempt to) collect the person's name, email address, company and country, before the tutorial(s) can be downloaded.